# how to use findAndModify() function in mongo

Tags: mongodb

with this data in collection

```
var documents = [{
      _id : 1
    , title: "Buy milk"
    , priority: 5
    , started: false
    , done: false
    , startTime: null
    , endTime: null
    }, {
      _id : 2
    , title: "Become a Billionaire"
    , priority: 1
    , started: false
    , done: false
    , startTime: null
    , endTime: null
    }, {
      _id : 3
    , title: "Play DOOM"
    , priority: 1000
    , started: false
    , done: false
    , startTime: null
    , endTime: null
    }
  ]
```

i m using findAndModify() function with following parameters:

```
db.test.findAndModify({started:false},{priority:-1},{$set:{started:true}},{new:true})
```

i m getting this error again n again

---

findAndModifyFailed failed: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "need remove or
 update" } at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:399

---

can anybody tell me where i m making the mistake,
thanks

Comment: Well it says the problem, you need to specify an OP type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can either `update` or `remove` a document atomically with `findAndModify`

```
db.test.findAndModify({
    query:{started:false, priority:1},
    update:{$set : {started:true}},
    new:true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[`findAndModify`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) is used for a single document. [`update`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) can be used for a number of documents when `multi` is set to `true`.